# Get a comma number from a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a string like:

```
$string = "P 1 BNN-01 HV A7weg letsel (Auto) A7 Re 138,3 HASKERHORNE.";
```

I want to get the "138,3" part to use as variable like `$number = "138,3"`. I think I can use `preg_match_all` and then use the matches array, but I cant find the correct regex for it.

So the string can contain multiple numbers, but I need only the one with a comma in it. It can contain a maximum of 3 numbers before the comma, and only one after.

```
$pattern = "^-?\d+(,\d+)*(\.\d+(e\d+)?)?$";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Comment: `$pattern = '~\d+,\d+~';` and use `preg_match` since you need a single match.

Comment: what Wiktor wrote: `$number = preg_match('~\d+,\d+~', $string, $matches) ? $matches[0] : null;`